# Using map and reduce to get array of objects

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ecmascript-6

I'm having an array of

```
var c = [{name: 'John'}, {name: 'John'}, {name: 'Tom'}];
```

I want to use the reduce method and map to get this following result:

```
result = [
    { name: "John", occurence: 2 },
    { name: "Tom", occurence: 1 }
  ]
```

Here's an attempt I have tried but still not fully getting it. https://jsfiddle.net/joeSaad/up3ddfzz/

```js
c = [{
  name: 'John'
}, {
  name: 'John'
}, {
  name: 'Simon'
}];

var d = c.reduce((countMap, word) => {
  countMap[word.name] = ++countMap[word.name] || 1;
  return countMap
}, []);

var e = c.reduce((countMap, word) => {
  q = [];
  countMap[word.name] = ++countMap[word.name] || 1;
  var p = {
    name: word.name,
    occurence: countMap[word.name]
  }
  q.push(p);
  return q
}, []);

console.log(e);
```

Help much appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you forget to post the attempt?

Comment: @AndrewL. thanks! just edited the question

Comment: @mike-c it seems that the run now in my jsfiddle is not working..

Comment: @JoeSaad What do you mean and why did you ping me? I didn't alter your JSFiddle code at all. I just copied it into a runnable snippet inside of your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're definitely on the right track working with reduce, but I would separate the computations into two distinct steps

```js
let c = [{name: 'John'}, {name: 'John'}, {name: 'Tom'}];

const pairs = o=> Object.keys(o).map(k=> [k, o[k]])

let count = c.reduce((acc, {name}) => {
  if (acc[name] === undefined)
    return Object.assign(acc, { [name]: 1 })
  else
    return Object.assign(acc, { [name]: acc[name] + 1 })
}, {})

var result = pairs(count).map(([name, occurences]) => ({name, occurences}))

console.log(result)
//=> [ { name: 'John', occurences: 2 }, { name: 'Tom', occurences: 1 } ]
```

---

You could abstract these behaviours into distinct functions like this

```js
// convert an object to [[key,value]] pairs
const pairs = o=> Object.keys(o).map(k=> [k, o[k]])

// count unique instances of a property value in an array of objects
const countBy = (prop, xs)=> {
  return xs.reduce((acc, x)=> {
    let y = x[prop]
    if (acc[y] === undefined)
      return Object.assign(acc, { [y]: 1 })
    else
      return Object.assign(acc, { [y]: acc[y] + 1 })
  }, {})
}

// your data
let c = [{name: 'John'}, {name: 'John'}, {name: 'Tom'}]

// then chain it all together
let result = pairs(countBy('name', c)).map(([name, occurences]) => ({name, occurences}))

console.log(result)
//=> [ { name: 'John', occurences: 2 }, { name: 'Tom', occurences: 1 } ]
```

---

ES6 also offers [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) which is pretty good for doing this kind of computation.

This code reads a little nicer to me and is a little more semantically correct. Our previous code was doing the exact same thing, only it was using a plain object. `Map` is a data structure specifically designed for this `key->value` data, so that makes Map a better choice.

The only problem with this is, if your codebase isn't already using Maps in some way, introducing them just for this might be the wrong move.

```js
// convert a Map to an array of pairs
const mpairs = m=> [...m.entries()]

// countBy this time uses Map
const countBy = (prop, xs)=> {
  return xs.reduce((m, x)=> {
    let y = x[prop]
    if (m.has(y))
      return m.set(y, m.get(y) + 1)
    else
      return m.set(y, 1)
  }, new Map)
}

// your data
let c = [{name: 'John'}, {name: 'John'}, {name: 'Tom'}]

// then chain it all together
let result = mpairs(countBy('name', c)).map(([name, occurences]) => ({name, occurences}))

console.log(result)
//=> [ { name: 'John', occurences: 2 }, { name: 'Tom', occurences: 1 } ]
```

Comment: This definitely works. Thanks @naomik I still am trying to understand why we have const pairs. We are not using it. Also i don't quiet get the second approach. Thanks again!

Comment: We are definitely using it `pairs`; read the code more closely. The second section was meant suggest that you should wrap this stuff up in a function so that it doesn't clutter up the rest of your code. I added some notes there and also added a third section which shows how to do the same computation using a more semantic data structure.